# Ошибка CMake 178

Tags: c++, переменные, объявление, extern

Уважаемые знатоки!

Решаю такую задачу:

> Задание. Проект симулятора работы компьютера Что нужно сделать
> Реализуйте простую модель работы персонального компьютера в качестве
> многомодульного проекта. В компьютере несколько основных, условных
> компонент.
>
> Центральный процессор (cpu) — должен иметь функцию compute, которая
> складывает 8 чисел из буфера оперативной памяти (см. далее) и выводит
> результат в консоль.
>
> Оперативная память (ram) — содержит буфер на 8 целых чисел, которые
> можно заполнить функцией write и считать функцией read.
>
> Жёсткий диск (disk) — имеет в себе две функции, save и load. Функция
> save должна сохранить состояние 8 чисел из оперативной памяти на
> постоянный носитель в файл data.txt. Функция load — загрузить их с
> носителя в оперативную память.
>
> Графическая карта (gpu) — выводит в консоль 8 чисел из оперативной
> памяти.
>
> Клавиатура (kbd) — позволяет ввести 8 чисел и разместить их в
> оперативной памяти.
>
> Каждая компонента должна располагаться в отдельном модуле, с отдельным
> заголовочным файлом. Основной модуль программы (main.cpp) должен
> считывать пользовательский ввод команды, которая соответствует
> отдельным функциям устройств: sum (вычисление суммы), save (сохранить
> в файл), load (загрузить из файла), input (ввести с клавиатуры),
> display (вывести на экран). Команда exit — выходит из программы.

Строю следующий проект:

https://github.com/alexeysklemin/cmkeStuding/tree/main/comp/computers

Выдает следующие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

направте в правильную сторону. Где я свернул не туда

Comment: Небось заинклудили .cpp-файлы? Или определили что-то не то в заголовочных?

Comment: а можно подробнее я не до конца поял
Попутно:
абыл добавить:

Cmake --version 3.18.4

gcc -version 10.2.1

goal OS Debian 11

Answer (score 0):

У вас, как я и предполагал, в `ram.h` есть определение

```
int ram[8] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

которое из-за включения `ram.h`в разные .cpp-файлы приводит к тому, что у вас в каждом файле свой `int ram[8]`, так что нарушено ODR - правило одного определения, и при компоновке компоновщик не знает, что делать с несколькими одинаковыми сущностями с одинаковым именем, для которых в каждом файле выделена своя память...

Напишите в `ram.h`

```
extern int ram[8];
```

а вот это

```
int ram[8] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

перенесите в какой-то ***один*** .cpp-файл.

CMake в полной мере ни при чем.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Но к сожалению в локальной версии я писал extern int ram[8];
А в  ram.срр писал int ram[8] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
К сожалению либо та же ошибка либо ошибка о том что ram не определяли

Comment: Еще раз и медленно: у вас ошибка multiple definition этой самой `ram`. Значит, вы определяете переменную несколько раз. "Я все сделал, как надо, а ошибка остается" мне писали много раз, и каждый раз, когда просил код, оказывалось, что сделано было неверно. Разбираться, что вы в очередной раз сделали не так, особенно при том, что кода в вопросе нет, только ссылка - не собираюсь. Кстати, я проверил - сделал, как написал - и все нормально собралось. Вы точно что-то делали или просто написали, что не получается? :)

Comment: да разве я ж спорю

Comment: А разве нет?...

Comment: Я понять не могу. Сейчас прошелся по всем файлам. Везде инклуд с ram.h выкорчевовывал. прошелся опять тот же номер ошибки.

Comment: Еще раз. В `ram.h` **вместо** `int ram[8] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` пишем `extern int ram[8];` . В `main.cpp` , **и только в нем одном** добавляем `int ram[8] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};`. Всё. Да, убеждаемся, что компилируются и линкуются именно эти файлы :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Я что-то после паузы туплю по жесткому. У меня вопрос могу ли я в майне int ram[8] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; написать в области глобальной видимости или это надо написать в 
int main(){
}

Comment: Конечно в глобальной!